# How I can get fired event from JS function without passing event parameter?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

Is it possible to get the JavaScript fired event from called JavaScript function **without passing any event parameter?**

Here is the sample code:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script>
      function myFunction()
      {
        // How I will get from here the fired event  ??
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p id="paragraghhh" onclick="myFunction()">
       Click on this paragraph. An alert box will
       show which element triggered the event.
    </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the significance of not passing event parameters?

Comment: Use a proper event handler, not inline JS. Problem solved !

Comment: @Rodik : actually I want it to implement in primefaces there in `<p;ajax>` from `onstart` attribute I called a js function which doesnot support `event` parameter. When I pass `event` parameter then in`alert(event.type)` is displaying `undefined`. So I want to do this with out passing event parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Within a JavaScript function, you can reference the this.event attribute.

For example,

```
function myFunction(){
  alert(this.event.type);
}
```

Alerts the JS event, which in this case is 'click'

Comment: in this case, this will be window object

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
onclick="myFunction(event)"
```

JS:

```
function myFunction(e)
{
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

OR:

```
onclick="myFunction.call(this)"
```

JS:

```
function myFunction()
{
    console.log(this);
}
```

Better solution:

```
document.getElementById('paragraghhh').addEventListener('click', function(){
     console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I want to do this without passing any parameter. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

Just change HTML to

```
<p id="paragraghhh" onclick="myFunction(event)">
  Click on this paragraph. An alert box will
  show which element triggered the event.
</p>
```

And JS to

```
function myFunction(event)
{
  // Handle event
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply, but my requirement is with out passing any parameter.. is it possible??

Comment: I want to get click event, and to propagate from here.